# mup deploy to DO

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-up

I tried to deploy to my DO with mup

```
got the following error

gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   '/root/.node-gyp/0.10.31/common.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.node-gyp/0.10.31',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-container/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
    gyp info spawn make
    gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
    gyp info ok 
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
    bash: line 107: wait-for-mongo: command not found
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    ' of package 'npm-container'
    make: Entering directory `/opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-container/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak/build'
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/weakref/src/weakref.o
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/weakref.node
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/weakref.node: Finished
      COPY Release/weakref.node
    make: Leaving directory `/opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-container/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak/build'

    > fibers@1.0.1 install /opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
    > node ./build.js

    `linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
    Binary is fine; exiting
    underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

    semver@2.2.1 node_modules/semver

    source-map-support@0.2.5 node_modules/source-map-support
    └── source-map@0.1.29 (amdefine@0.1.0)

    fibers@1.0.1 node_modules/fibers
    meteor stop/waiting
    meteor start/running, process 18068
    Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
```

the log shows only one error couple of times

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at net.js:1146:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Script restart attempt #1
 >> stepping down to gid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to uid: meteoruse
```

Anyone had in this situation before?

what is the issue here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First visit to your app and apply `stop meteor`. Then try to restart the server and deploy again.